# Looping through datalist fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to process the selection from a datalist but the forech loop where I'm looping through the items in the datalist does not work. Basically if the checkbox is checked, I want to get the email address which is in the tooltip of the chekc box. The datalist count is zero. Can someone help me with this?

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" selectedIndex="0"  FadeTransitions="true" FramesPerSecond="40" TransitionDuration="250" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" HeaderCssClass="Header">
            <Panes>
                <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSM" runat="server" Width="207px" Text="Users" Font-Bold="true"  CssClass="GeneralText"  /><br /><br />
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <div class="emailleftcolumm">
                            <asp:DataList ID="dlSM" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" OnItemCommand="dlSM_ItemCommand" 
                                 EnableViewState="false" Width="207px" OnItemDataBound="dlSM_ItemDataBound">
                                <HeaderStyle BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Inset" Font-Bold="true" />
                                <HeaderTemplate> 
                                   Select All <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstname") + " " + Eval("lastname") + ", " + Eval("acronym") %>' 
                                        CssClass="GeneralText" ToolTip='<%# Eval("email") + ";" + Eval("altemail") %>'/>                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <div id="altbgcolor">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstname") + " " + Eval("lastname") + ", " + Eval("acronym") %>'  
                                            ToolTip='<%# Eval("email") + ";" + Eval("altemail") %>' CssClass="GeneralText" />                                        </div>
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

The button click event handler looks like this:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _mailto = string.Empty;
        string _subject = txtSubject.Text;
        string _message = txtMessage.Text;

        DataList DataList1 = (DataList)FindControl("DataList1");
        foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelector = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkSelector");
            if (chkSelector.Checked)
            {
                _mailto += chkSelector.ToolTip + ";";
            }
        }

        // do mail call

        // Clean up
        lblEmailConfirm.Font.Bold = true;
        lblEmailConfirm.Text = "Subject: " + _subject + " Message: " + _message;
        txtSubject.Text = string.Empty;
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: The ID of your DataList is `dlSM` not `DataList1`. Where is the `btnSend`? Why are you seraching for the DataList with FindControl?

Comment: @Tim: I've corrected the ID but no use. The btnSend is outside the accordion and is part of the form you click on to send the email. It fires, no issues there. Since posting this I did the following: DataList dlSM = (DataList)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("Accordion1").FindControl("AccordionPane1").FindControl("dlSM");. The flow goes into the foreach but quits on the first iteration.

Comment: @Tim: How else should I search for the DataList if not with FindControl?

Comment: Have you tried `Accordion1.FindControl("dlSM")`? It might be [an Accordion issue](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2007/01/08/AJAX-Control-Library-Accordion-Problems.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Setting viewstate to true did the trick - who new? (well Adrian did...)

Comment: Thanks, you should accept this answer. I'll give +1 for this, it's a first on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
DataList DataList1 = (DataList)FindControl("DataList1");
```

This is likely supposed to be

```
DataList DataList1 = (DataList)FindControl("dlSM");
```

based on what you provided.  I don't see a control with the id of DataList1 right now.

Comment: But wouldn't `DataList1.Items` throw a nullref when it's not found?

Comment: @Jared: I just commented on Tim's post. I made the correction as you both suggesting bu still no results.